# How use pyrogram chatlist (JoinChatlistInvite)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, pyrogram

I got a ChatList (all chats), but I don't know how I joined all chats with 1 request.

`check_list = await client.invoke(functions.chatlists.CheckChatlistInvite(slug=chat_list))` 
I have 1 option, join each chat separately, but maybe somebody know

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.